# Vuex cannot find object in object, returns undefined

Tags: json, laravel, vuex

I'm trying to access an object in my Vuex state winthin an action. However i cant seem to access all object keys. I can access name, but not role.

This is the object:

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ionas Skopelitis",
    "role": {
        "id": 1,
        "rolename": "Member",
        "privileges": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "role_id": 1,
                "name": "post"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Using this line:
`const user = this.state.userData.role;`

my console logs `undefined`

To no avail i cant get the roles and the privileges. What can i use to get an array of only the 'privileges'?

Comment: Please, show us how the action looks like and if you are using mapActions in your component, show it to us too. If you want to only get that information, consider to use a getter ir state

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is:

```
const user = this.$store.state.userData.role
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not, i'm trying to access it within an action.